# ¿Existe el concepto de relaciones unidireccionales o bidireccionales en el ORM Django?

Tags: php, java, python, django, java-ee

Tengo una duda existencial enorme al tratar de aprender el ORM de Django en Python. Resulta que en [Hibernate de Java](https://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/06/hibernate-parte-3-relaciones-uno-uno.html) y en [Doctrine2 de PHP](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html), cuando se realizan relaciones **One2One, One2Many, Many2One y Many2Many** existe el concepto de que una relación es **unidireccional** o **bidireccional**, esto según si defino la relación solo de un lado de las tablas relacionadas o si defino la relación de ambos lados de las tablas relacionadas. Pero en el ORM de Django en Python no he encontrado en ningún lado información al respecto. ¿Alguien puede darme luz al respecto? ¿Existe en el ORM Django relaciones bidireccionales y unidireccionales? ¿Si existe, como se manejan esos conceptos y porque? ¿Si no existe, porque no existen esos conceptos y como es la alternativa del concepto?¿Pueden darme algunos ejemplos?

Comment: Hola, recuerda realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a [ask] para que tengas buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez esto sea de ayuda :)
https://medium.com/hackernoon/django-orm-relationships-cheat-sheet-14433d6cf68c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIJI5U0BWr0
Saludos.

Comment: Por favor revisa como responder. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer